# Is there a way to enable Two-factor authentication for my apple id without any physical device?

Tags: two-factor-authentication

Apple has stopped publishing my apps in appstore, because my appleId has to be enabled with "Two-factor authentication" first. Now I have no MAC nor any iOS Phone / Tablet anymore.

How can I enable "Two-factor authentication" without to be bounded to any physical device. I can still manage the disabled apps in "Apple Store Connect", but I am forced to enable "Two-factor authentication".

Answer (score 3):

No, you require a physical device to set up two-factor authentication.

> Two-factor authentication is available to iCloud and iTunes users with at least one device that's using the latest iOS or macOS.

[Availability of two-factor authentication for Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT205075)