# How to prevent being locked out of AppleID with stolen iPhone

Tags: iphone, security, apple-id, password, keychain

The [WSJ Video](https://www.wsj.com/articles/stolen-iphone-passcode-security-tips-how-to-protect-data-2c4a3be7) indicates that all that is necessary to gain access to the password keychain and lock me out is for the bad actor to:

1. "shoulder surf" to acquire password
2. acquire physical access to the iPhone (steal it)
3. immediately change the AppleID password with password in step 1

Bad actors are following the above script to gain control of the AppleID including the password keychain for financial theft.  The video indicates that the 6-digit code is all that is necessary to allow the AppleID password to be changed.

I would think that a more secure method is to require the AppleID password to be changed using 2FA that requires a second Apple device, like an Apple Watch and not password recovery via email.

If the goal is to prevent the bad actor from locking out the rightful AppleIDowner:

- **Is there a mechanism to require the user (i.e. bad actor) to input something other than the 6-digit password (perhaps the current AppleID password) to change the AppleID password?**
- **How to require AppleID password to change AppleID password on iPhone?**

Bonus:  How to invoke 2FA (like when adding your AppleID to a new Macintosh account) to change AppleID password?.

Comment: A "bonus" question is nothing more than a different topic than the main one being asked.  Questions with multiple topics are closed for better focus.  It's also been addressed already:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/365373/119271

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a mechanism to require the user (i.e. bad actor) to input something other than the 6-digit password (perhaps the current AppleID password) to change the AppleID password?

This is what bio-metric authentication - TouchID and FaceID - is for.  There are only three times when you *must* enter a passcode:

- When you wake in the morning
- When the phone boots or reboots
- When you manually lock it to disable FaceID (Press Power and Volume button)

Bio-metric authentication has been available on the iPhone since the 5S. Whether you use bio-metric authentication by choice or by necessity, you must take responsibility for the security of your passcode much like you would with your ATM pin code.

Your iPhone is treated as your primary "trusted device" like an RSA Secure Token would be.  So, in the event you lose this device and the unlikely event that someone shoulder-surfed you at one of the three instances described above, it's incumbent upon you to take steps to "lock it out."

#### Apple's [FindMy Feature](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph09b087eda/ios)

- Can be done from another iDevice
- [Apple Watch can locate it](https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/find-devices-apd092474c11/watchos), make it play a sound, and even lock it remotely
- Can be accessed via *any* computer through [iCloud.com/find](https://www.icloud.com/find)

It's important to remember that no device can be 100% secure - even the RSA SecureID tokens (which are used in DoD) or Yubikeys; those devices can be stolen as well.  A well-placed shoulder surfer or keystroke logger can grab your password just like they can grab your phone.  The last mile of security is the user, and this is where you can stop any potential security breach.